# img tag inside the a tag isnt responding to the background change option

Tags: html, css

hello i have a problem in my code .. i want to change the color of an image inside the a tag ... mainly to be used as a refresh page

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bacon Fansite</title></head>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\workspace\external_css\styles.css">


<body>
  <a href="file:///D:/workspace/web_dev/bacon_file.html"><img class="refresh" src="C:/Users/GOD/Pictures/sgfgfg.jpg" alt="refresh" background-color=black > </a>
   <h1 id="baconbacon">I Love Bacon</h1>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>

  <img class="bacon" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/240/apple/118/bacon_1f953.png" alt="bacon-img">
  <img class="brocolli" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/google/263/black-heart_1f5a4.png" alt="dark heart " height="160px">


</body>
<hr>
</html>
```

this is my html code , i have an image inside 'a' tag over here
and in the css .. its back ground color isnt changing

```
body{ 
    background-color: #f1e189;
}
h1{ 
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 78.5px;
    color: rgb(79, 0, 0);
}

hr{ 
    
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: green;
    width: 25%;
    border-style: none;
    border-top-style:dotted; 
    height: 10px;
}
p{ 
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
    color:#B22222;
}
.bacon{
    background-color: brown ;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}
.brocolli{ 
    background-color: brown;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
#baconbacon{ 
    color:#931a25 ;
}
.bacon:hover{ 
    background-color:#b5651d;
}
.brocolli:hover{ 
    background-color: #b5651d;
}
img{ 
    background-color: #f1e189;
}
.refresh{ 
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color:#f1e189;
}
```

this is the css code
if someone can tell please what to do in order to change the color of the image ONLY which is present inside the a tag

Comment: The image inside your <a> tag is a jpg, which means it likely has a solid background, not a transparent one like the other png images you're using. You need to convert it to a format that allows transparent backgrounds, like .png, and then remove the solid background.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<img class="refresh" style="background-color:black" href="img-path-here">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a wrapper outside of your picture, place the picture in it and change the background of the wrapper

or when you actually want the picture to be black use a filter with brightness 0;

```css
body{ 
    background-color: #f1e189;
}
h1{ 
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 78.5px;
    color: rgb(79, 0, 0);
}

hr{ 
    
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: green;
    width: 25%;
    border-style: none;
    border-top-style:dotted; 
    height: 10px;
}
p{ 
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
    color:#B22222;
}
.bacon{
    background-color: brown ;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}
.brocolli{ 
    background-color: brown;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
#baconbacon{ 
    color:#931a25 ;
}
.bacon:hover{ 
    background-color:#b5651d;
}
.brocolli:hover{ 
    background-color: #b5651d;
}
.wrapper{
  background:black;
  width:100px;
}
.wrapper img{ 
    width:100%;
}

a img{
 width:100px;
 filter:brightness(0);
}
.ref
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bacon Fansite</title></head>
  


<body>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354679/img-tag-inside-the-a-tag-isnt-responding-to-the-background-change-option"><div class="wrapper"><img class="refresh" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.eremedia.com/uploads/2012/08/24111405/stackoverflow-logo-700x467.png" alt="refresh" > </div></a>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354679/img-tag-inside-the-a-tag-isnt-responding-to-the-background-change-option"><img class="refresh" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.eremedia.com/uploads/2012/08/24111405/stackoverflow-logo-700x467.png" alt="refresh" > </a>
   <h1 id="baconbacon">I Love Bacon</h1>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, nbaco, bacon, bacon</p>
  <p>bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon, bacon</p>

  <img class="bacon" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/240/apple/118/bacon_1f953.png" alt="bacon-img">
  <img class="brocolli" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/google/263/black-heart_1f5a4.png" alt="dark heart " height="160px">


</body>
<hr>
</html>
```